# Issue with SaltStack Docker-py port binding tcp and udp to the same port

Tags: docker, salt-stack

Hello I am having an issue with configuring both TCP and UDP to the same port via SaltStack and the dockerio module. In this case I am trying to configure DNS for both TCP and UDP port 53.

The environment is the same for both master and minion, the details are:

```
Ubuntu 15.04
lxc-docker 1.6.2 package (from deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main)
salt-common 2015.5.0+ds-1utopic1 package
salt-minion 2015.5.0+ds-1utopic1 package (salt-minion 2015.5.0 (Lithium))
salt-master 2015.5.0+ds-1utopic1 package (salt-master 2015.5.0 (Lithium))
docker-py 1.2.2
```

From the Dockerfile for the container:

```
EXPOSE 53
EXPOSE 53/udp
```

The relevant config for SaltStack from the state.sls file for this container (inside docker.running):

```
{% set hostport1            = '53' %}
{% set hostport1_proto      = 'udp' %} 
{% set hostport2            = '53' %}
{% set hostport2_proto      = 'tcp' %}
...
        - ports:
            "{{ hostport1 }}/{{ hostport1_proto }}":
                HostIp: ""
                HostPort: "{{ hostport1 }}"
            "{{ hostport2 }}/{{ hostport2_proto }}":
                HostIp: ""
                HostPort: "{{ hostport2 }}"
...
```

The container starts up and runs successfully. The issue is only the TCP port is ever mapped, the UDP port remains unmapped. It does not matter which order I list the TCP and UDP port only the TCP port is ever mapped through docker.

```
From docker ps -a:
0.0.0.0:53->53/tcp, 53/udp
```

I have looked through all the information I can find and I have seen older closed issues related to docker-py but nothing recent and seemingly no one else having this issue.

I have confirmed that running the container manually does work and map the ports correctly:

```
docker run ... -p 53:53 -p 53:53/udp ...
docker ps -a
... 0.0.0.0:53->53/tcp, 0.0.0.0:53->53/udp ...
```

So this confirms to me the source of this issue or misconfiguration is in either docker-py or SaltStack. Any information or configuration tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The source of this issue is the configuration of the HostIp: field. Using a blank value of "" is not acceptable. Instead setting the HostIp to "0.0.0.0" resolves this issue completely. The documentation in this regard is not clear.

Much thanks and credit goes to mosen on #salt channel on Freenode IRC.